# Data augmentation: ImageDataGenerator vs openCV

Tags: deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, computer-vision, convolutional-neural-network

I would like to increase the data in my dataset to create a CNN deep learning classification model.

Which is better for the model, using data augmentation by `ImageDataGenerator` or using openCV to increase the data?

By the way, I am using Keras and floydhub.

Comment: Since you are using Keras, why not start withe Keras [ImageDataGenerator](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html)?

Comment: @user12075 I edit the question according to what I mean

Comment: [Here](https://towardsdatascience.com/image-augmentation-examples-in-python-d552c26f2873) is tutorial on how to make your own custom generator using opencv. Which you can expand as much as you want with your ideas.

Answer (score 2):

An example with library imgaug, Keras, ImageDataGenerator and flow_from_dataframe:

```
import imgaug as ia
import imgaug.augmenters as iaa

seq = iaa.Sequential([
        iaa.Crop(px=(0, 16)), 
        # crop images from each side by 0 to 16px (randomly chosen)
        iaa.Fliplr(0.5), 
        # horizontally flip 50% of the images
        iaa.GaussianBlur(sigma=(0, 3.0)) 
        # blur images with a sigma of 0 to 3.0
    ])

def augment(img):
        seq_det = seq.to_deterministic()
        aug_image = seq_det.augment_image(img)

        return applications.inception_resnet_v2.preprocess_input(aug_image)

train_generator = image.ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=augment)

train_flow = train_generator.flow_from_dataframe(
        dataframe=train_df,
        directory=train_data_dir,
        x_col="path",
        y_col=columns,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode="other",
        target_size=(img_height ,img_width),
        shuffle=True
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Keras' `ImageDataGenerator` doesn't offer much support by itself for data augmentation. However it has a parameter called `preprocessing_function` which allows you to use custom augmentors with it.

I personally use [imgaug](https://github.com/aleju/imgaug) which offers virtually any augmentation you can think of and works well with `ImageDataGenerator` like I said.

Comment: Can I use imgaug if I read the images from a directory? I am not using numpy images..

Comment: @N.IT you use the `ImageDataGenerator` to load the images just like you currently do it. imgaug just lets you make augmentation on-the-fly.